# Android new fragment (via naviagtion components) isn't working with talkback

Tags: android, talkback

It's very weird behavior.  Lots of other fragments in this app (via the nav components), just this new one has the problem.   It's really quite a simple fragment.  Just 3 menu items, an image, and a list of key/value pairs.   Talkback doesn't see the title, the menu items, or the content.   However, if I rotate the screen, navigate to a another fragment and back, then it works.

It's not happening on all devices.  One of my users and one test phone are reproducing it.  They are both Samsung devices running Android 12.   I can't reproduce it on a Pixel 6 running Android 13.

Both TalkBack and Select to Speak see the issue.  Running the Accessibility Scanner, fixes the issue (like rotating or navigating to a child and back).

Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookCoverImage"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/google_phone_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/google_phone_height"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/status"
            android:labelFor="@id/title_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bookCoverImage" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:labelFor="@id/title_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/status" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/author"
            android:labelFor="@id/author_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/publisher"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/publisher"
            android:labelFor="@id/publisher_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/author" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/publishDate"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/publishDate"
            android:labelFor="@id/publishDate_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/publisher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/isbn"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/isbn"
            android:labelFor="@id/isbn_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/publishDate" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/length"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/length"
            android:labelFor="@id/length_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/isbn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/source"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/source"
            android:labelFor="@id/source_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/length" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/voice"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/voice"
            android:labelFor="@id/voice_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/source" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/importDate"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/import_date"
            android:labelFor="@id/importDate_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/voice" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statusMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:labelFor="@id/statusMessageValue"
            android:text="@string/status_message"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/importDate" />


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/value_barrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="end"
            app:barrierMargin="16dp"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="title,author,publisher,length,publishDate,isbn,source,voice,importDate,bookCoverImage,status,statusMessage" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/status"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/value_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/status"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/value_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/author"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/value_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/author"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/publisher_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/publisher"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/value_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/publisher"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/publishDate_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/publishDate"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/value_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/publishDate"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/isbn_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/isbn"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/value_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/isbn"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/length_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/length"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/value_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/length"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/source_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/source"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/value_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/source"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/voice_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/voice"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/value_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/voice"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/importDate_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/importDate"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/value_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/importDate"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statusMessageValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/value_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/statusMessage"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Talkback doesn't even see the navigate back button.   It literally thinks there are no controls to be read.

Comment: I rewrote the fragment with Compose, that didn't change things a bit.   It's still broken on the same devices.

Comment: I still haven't solved this, but now I do see a pattern.  There are two fragments that exhibit this behavior, we navigate to both of them from a context menu on a recyclerview.  I've tried decoupling the context menu action from the navigation (by handling the nav in post on a handler), but so far without success.

Comment: Still not solved, but I have more info.  It appears to be related navigating from a context menu.  I recently added accessibility actions to the app, I can navigate to those views via the accessibility actions and everything works fine.